# Database.EnsureCreated() generates InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, invalidoperationexception

I'm setting my first steps in dependency injection related programming in an `EntityFramework` environment, and I have following `Exception`:

`Database` is of the type `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseFacade`.

The `Database.EnsureCreated();` line gives following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException:
> 'No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Element'.
> The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type:
> cannot bind 'ipAddress', 'strategy', 'bufferSize' in 'Element(string name, IPAddress ipAddress, short port, IStrategy strategy, short bufferSize)';
> cannot bind 'ipAddress'                           in 'Element(IPAddress ipAddress, short port)'.'

Apparently `name` and `port` are well handled, but not the others. I've been looking into the constructors and the database related configuration, but I don't see how `name` and `port` seem to be treated better than the others. Does anybody have an idea?

The properties look as follows:

```
public Guid Id { get; private set; }
public string Name { get; private set; }
public ElementStatus Status { get; private set; }
public IPAddress Ip { get; }
public short Port { get; }
public short BufferSize { get; }
public IStrategy Strategy { get; }
...
```

The constructors look as follows:

```
public Element(string name, IPAddress ipAddress, short port, IStrategy Strategy, short bufferSize = 8192)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress.ToString()))
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid IP address");

    this.Name = name;
    this.Ip = ipAddress;
    this.Port = port;
    BufferSize = bufferSize;
    Strategy = Strategy;
}

public Element(IPAddress ipAddress, short port)
{
    this.Ip = ipAddress;
    this.Port = port;
}
```

The database configuration looks as follows:

```
public class Configurations :
    IEntityTypeConfiguration<Element>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Element> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(o => o.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Property(o => o.Name).IsRequired();
        builder.HasIndex(o => o.Name).IsUnique();
        builder.Property(o => o.Ip).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(o => o.Port).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(o => o.Status).IsRequired();

        builder.HasIndex("Ip", "Port").IsUnique();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a parameterless constructor should solve this problem as this constructor is not fulfilling all required properties.

```
public Element(IPAddress ipAddress, short port)
{
    this.Ip = ipAddress;
    this.Port = port;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that the constructor parameters can't be bound to the type properties. Most of the parameter names match a property name but you have a parameter named `ipAddress` and a property named `Ip`, so they presumably are not being mapped. If you change one or the other so they match then I think you should be OK.

Comment: I've modified it, but the problem remains.